# cannot use type interface {} as type person in assignment: need type assertion

Tags: go

I try to convert `interface{}` to struct `person`...

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func FromJson(jsonSrc string) interface{} {
    var obj interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonSrc), &obj)

    return obj
}

func main() {

    type person struct {
        Name string
        Age  int
    }
    json := `{"Name": "James", "Age": 22}`

    actualInterface := FromJson(json)

    fmt.Println("actualInterface")
    fmt.Println(actualInterface)

    var actual person

    actual = actualInterface // error fires here -------------------------------

    // -------------- type assertion always gives me 'not ok'
    // actual, ok := actualInterface.(person)
    // if ok {

    //  fmt.Println("actual")
    //  fmt.Println(actual)
    // } else {
    //  fmt.Println("not ok")
    //  fmt.Println(actual)
    // }
}
```

... But got error:

```
cannot use type interface {} as type person in assignment: need type assertion
```

To solve this error I tried to use type assertion `actual, ok := actualInterface.(person)` but always got `not ok`.

## [Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/JDZDPNlLnM)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way to handle this is to pass a pointer to the output value to your decoding helper function. This avoids type assertions in your application code.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func FromJson(jsonSrc string, v interface{}) error {
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonSrc), v)

}

func main() {
    type person struct {
        Name string
        Age  int
    }
    json := `{"Name": "James", "Age": 22}`

    var p person
    err := FromJson(json, &p)

    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you're creating an empty interface to begin with, and telling `json.Unmarshal` to unmarshal into it. While you've defined a `person` type, `json.Unmarshal` has no way of knowing that that's what you intend the type of the JSON to be. To fix this, move the definition of `person` to the top level (that is, move it out of the body of `main), and change`FromJson` to this:

```
func FromJson(jsonSrc string) interface{} {
    var obj person{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonSrc), &obj)

    return obj
}
```

Now, when you return `obj`, the `interface{}` that's returned has `person` as its underlying type. You can run this code on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/y1g2cAb43I).

By the way, your code is a bit un-idiomatic. I left the original Playground link unmodified except for my corrections so that it wouldn't be needlessly confusing. If you're curious, [here's a version](http://play.golang.org/p/q63xFWmhJR) that's cleaned up to be more idiomatic (including comments on why I made the changes I did).