# Why can't I use an empty interface that holds a concrete type of string as a return value in a function declared to return string?

Tags: go

I am a newcomer of go and recently I am following the instruction of *A Tour of Go*.
I am reading the chapter on *Interface* and I am really confused by the concept.

The code is as follows

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    testTypeAssertion()
}

func testTypeAssertion() string {
    var i interface{}="hello"
    fmt.Printf("type of i is %T",i)
    return i
//  return "hello"
}
```

In this case, it will cause error

```sh
# example
./prog.go:12:2: cannot use i (type interface {}) as type string in return argument: need type assertion
```

But if I comment `return i` and uncomment `return "hello"`, it goes like this

```sh
type of i is string
```

So why exactly do we need a type assertion here?
What's the type of `i` exactly?

I believe this question is different from [cannot use type interface {} as type person in assignment: need type assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437053/cannot-use-type-interface-as-type-person-in-assignment-need-type-assertion). Because in that question the poster is trying to assign an empty interface value to a variable that has a concrete self-defined type `person`. In my question, I am trying to figure out why an interface holding a concrete `string` value cannot be a return value of a function whose return value type is exactly `string`.

Thanks to [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)'s answer in the comment section and [bugstop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12277722/bugstop)'s answer. I will accept that it's caused by the different usage of *static type* and *dynamic type*. By the way, [Reality](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18208953/reality)'s answer is very interesting and really helped me to understand the whole concept!

Comment: maybe you should explictly cast at return for your purpose though I dont think that is the essence of interface - `return i.(string`)
ref - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-golang/#:~:text=In%20Go%20language%2C%20the%20interface,an%20instance%20of%20the%20interface.&text=Or%20in%20other%20words%2C%20the,it%20is%20a%20custom%20type.

Comment: The *static* type of `i` is `interface{}`, the *dynamic* type is `string`. The `Printf("%T...` will *always* print the dynamic type of the passed in argument. Why? Because the `Printf` parameter's *static* type is `interface{}`, so if it was implemented to print the static type then it would print `interface{}` for anything and everything. That would not be very helpful. If you want to know the *static* type of `i` you can pass a pointer to `i` to `Printf` which will then print `*static_type` as the type of the given argument. https://go.dev/play/p/caKewzFgAUQ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot use type interface {} as type person in assignment: need type assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437053/cannot-use-type-interface-as-type-person-in-assignment-need-type-assertion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's an interface value `i` with a dynamic type `string`.

It may be useful to read about:

- [How to determine an interface{} value's "real" type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372474/how-to-determine-an-interface-values-real-type)
- [Interfaces in Go](https://go101.org/article/interface.html)

Answer (score 4):

Think of an interface as a little box that holds a type and a value.  The box has methods that map to methods on the value in the box.

The statement `fmt.Printf("type of i is %T",i)` prints the type in the box, not the type of the box itself.  Reflect package trickery is required to print the type of `i`. but that's outside the scope of this question.

The statement `return i` does not compile because `interface{}` is not a `string`.  The box contains a string, but the box is not a `string`.

We can get the value out of the box using a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions): `return i.(string)`.  This statement panics if `i` does not contain a string.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` is of type `interface{}`, and its value is the string "hello". An interface is simply a method-set, and since  `interface{}` has no methods specified, all types satisfy it. Because of this, the assignment `i="hello"` works.

However, you cannot return an `interface{}` where a `string` is required, because `string` is not the same type as an `interface{}`. You could have returned a `string` where an `interface{}` is required, because a string implements `interface{}`.